# for loop and char in C

Tags: c, string, for-loop, char

I am trying to learn C language and I need some help in here.

I am trying to make a program for tic-tac-toe game.  I tried doing the first bit of it in main function but it did not work. However, when I used another function, it worked.  How and why did it work? ( both programmes are attached below).

Also, I used "%s" instead of "%c" in scanf with "square 1" and "square 2". 
Why doesn't "%c" work fine in here ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
// first program


#include <stdio.h>  

int main ()

{

int player;                                         
char square1; 
char square2;
char Nesta[9]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}; 
int player1;
int player2;


printf("choose one for x or two for o\n");  


scanf("%i", &player); 

if (player==1) 
{
    player1='x';
    player2='o';
}
else
{
    player1 ='o';
    player2='x';
}


printf(
       "1  +  2 + 3   \n"
       "---+----+-----\n"
       "4  +  5 + 6   \n"
       "---+----+-----\n"
       "7  +  8 + 9   \n"
       );


for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    printf("please enter the number of the sqaure "); 
    scanf("%s",&square1 );

    printf("please enter the number of the sqaure "); 
    scanf("%s",&square2 );

    for (int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
        if (square1 == Nesta[j])

        {
            Nesta[j]=player1;
            printf(
                   "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
                   "----+-----+--- \n"
                   "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
                   "----+-----+--- \n"
                   "%c  +  %c + %c \n", Nesta[0],Nesta[1], Nesta[2], Nesta[3],Nesta[4],Nesta[5],Nesta[6],Nesta[7],Nesta[8]);
        }
    }


    for (int k=0; k<9; ++k)
    {
        if (square2 == Nesta[k])

        {
            Nesta[k]=player2;
            printf(
                   "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
                   "----+-----+--- \n"
                   "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
                   "----+-----+--- \n"
                   "%c  +  %c + %c \n", Nesta[0],Nesta[1], Nesta[2], Nesta[3],Nesta[4],
                                         Nesta[5],Nesta[6],Nesta[7],Nesta[8]);
         }

       }
     }
      return 0; 
   }
```

it works just fine when using gamecont function!!

```
// the second program
#include <stdio.h> 

char Nesta[9]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}; 
int player1;
int player2;

int gamecont ()
{

char square2;

printf("please enter the number of the square "); 
scanf("%s",&square2 ); 

for (int j=0; j<9; ++j)

    if (square2 == Nesta[j])
      {
        Nesta[j]=player2;
        printf(
               "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
               "----+-----+--- \n"
               "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
               "----+-----+--- \n"
               "%c  +  %c + %c \n", Nesta[0],Nesta[1], Nesta[2], Nesta[3],Nesta[4],
                                    Nesta[5],Nesta[6],Nesta[7],Nesta[8]);
        }
    }


int main ()
{

int player;                                         
char square1; 

printf("choose one for x or two for o\n");  

scanf("%i", &player); 

if (player==1) 
{
    player1='x';
    player2='o';
}
else
{
    player1 ='o';
    player2='x';
}


printf(
       "1  +  2 + 3   \n"
       "---+----+-----\n"
       "4  +  5 + 6   \n"
       "---+----+-----\n"
       "7  +  8 + 9   \n"
       );



 for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
 {
 printf("please enter the number of the square  "); 
 scanf("%s",&square1 ); 

 for (int j=0; j<9; ++j)
 {
   if (square1 == Nesta[j])
    {  
        Nesta[j]=player1;

        printf(
               "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
               "----+-----+--- \n"
               "%c  +  %c + %c \n"
               "----+-----+--- \n"
               "%c  +  %c + %c \n", Nesta[0],Nesta[1], Nesta[2], Nesta[3],Nesta[4],Nesta[5],Nesta[6],Nesta[7],Nesta[8]);

gamecont() ;   
            }
}
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code please!

Comment: I mean properly - there are extra lines, there are no spaces in a new scope, etc. You just formatted it using the StackOverflow button, it's still far from being properly indented. Help us help you!

Comment: This `scanf("%s",&square1 );` is not only unsafe, it's undefined behaviour. If it doesn't do any funny things (like formatting the hard drive), it will write the 0-terminator right next to `square1`, stomping on any data that has the misfortune of being stored there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be clear when you say something "does not work".  Does not work in what sense?  The computer melts? Or something specific happens you were not expecting?  Then be specific.

WRT `%c` vs `%s`, keep in mind that when you enter data from the console you need to hit "enter", which feeds a '\n' character to the stdin buffer.  **That '\n' is still in the input buffer, waiting to be read by the next `scanf`.**

When you use `%s`, if there is a newline in the buffer, that will be skipped because`%s` strings do not include whitespace and leading whitespace is skipped by most type specifiers.  However, `%c` is always a single character.  Consider:

```
char c;
while (scanf("%c", &c)) printf("%d\n", c);
```

Everytime you enter a character (and hit enter) you'll get *two* numbers, the second of which is 10 (ascii `\n`).

Unfortunately, your use of %s is unsafe.  Try this instead:

```
scanf("%c%*c", &square);
```

The `*` means ignore, so this will remove the newline leaving the stdin buffer empty.  However, if the user enters more than one letter (or a space) something will still get left over.  You could make `square` a string and just use the first character, but that has pitfalls too.  One robust way to flush the input buffer is:

```
while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
```

If you do that after you use scanf, it will eat anything in the buffer after your capture, leaving it clear for the next time.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to vote up for your answer :). Thank you. You made it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code dump, you scan a c-string with %s to a character variable (square1 and square2). This is unsafe, you should scan a c-string to a character array, not to a single character.